# Uncaught exception - WordPress Site

Tags: wordpress, error

We've had CiviCRM Version 5.61.2 for WordPress installed on a Staging site for a week to determine if we can run it on our production environment.

The debug.log file for this website is as follows:

```
[16-Jun-2023 04:38:06 UTC] PHP Notice:  Function WP_User_Query::query was called <strong>incorrectly</strong>. User queries should not be run before the <code>plugins_loaded</code> hook. Please see <a href="https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/debugging-in-wordpress/">Debugging in WordPress</a> for more information. (This message was added in version 6.1.1.) in /nas/content/live/staloysiuscstg/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5865
[16-Jun-2023 04:38:10 UTC] PHP Notice:  Function WP_User_Query::query was called <strong>incorrectly</strong>. User queries should not be run before the <code>plugins_loaded</code> hook. Please see <a href="https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/debugging-in-wordpress/">Debugging in WordPress</a> for more information. (This message was added in version 6.1.1.) in /nas/content/live/staloysiuscstg/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5865
[16-Jun-2023 04:38:13 UTC] PHP Notice:  Function WP_User_Query::query was called <strong>incorrectly</strong>. User queries should not be run before the <code>plugins_loaded</code> hook. Please see <a href="https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/debugging-in-wordpress/">Debugging in WordPress</a> for more information. (This message was added in version 6.1.1.) in /nas/content/live/staloysiuscstg/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5865
[16-Jun-2023 04:38:15 UTC] PHP Notice:  Function WP_User_Query::query was called <strong>incorrectly</strong>. User queries should not be run before the <code>plugins_loaded</code> hook. Please see <a href="https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/debugging-in-wordpress/">Debugging in WordPress</a> for more information. (This message was added in version 6.1.1.) in /nas/content/live/staloysiuscstg/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5865
[19-Jun-2023 01:15:59 UTC] PHP Notice:  Function WP_User_Query::query was called <strong>incorrectly</strong>. User queries should not be run before the <code>plugins_loaded</code> hook. Please see <a href="https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/debugging-in-wordpress/">Debugging in WordPress</a> for more information. (This message was added in version 6.1.1.) in /nas/content/live/staloysiuscstg/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5865
[19-Jun-2023 01:16:03 UTC] PHP Notice:  Function WP_User_Query::query was called <strong>incorrectly</strong>. User queries should not be run before the <code>plugins_loaded</code> hook. Please see <a href="https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/debugging-in-wordpress/">Debugging in WordPress</a> for more information. (This message was added in version 6.1.1.) in /nas/content/live/staloysiuscstg/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5865
[19-Jun-2023 01:16:05 UTC] PHP Notice:  Function WP_User_Query::query was called <strong>incorrectly</strong>. User queries should not be run before the <code>plugins_loaded</code> hook. Please see <a href="https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/debugging-in-wordpress/">Debugging in WordPress</a> for more information. (This message was added in version 6.1.1.) in /nas/content/live/staloysiuscstg/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5865
[19-Jun-2023 01:16:07 UTC] PHP Notice:  Function WP_User_Query::query was called <strong>incorrectly</strong>. User queries should not be run before the <code>plugins_loaded</code> hook. Please see <a href="https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/debugging-in-wordpress/">Debugging in WordPress</a> for more information. (This message was added in version 6.1.1.) in /nas/content/live/staloysiuscstg/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5865
[20-Jun-2023 00:40:20 UTC] auditor:event=wp_login {"user_id":1,"blog_id":1,"event":"wp_login","current_user_id":0,"remote_addr":"122.199.33.74"}
[20-Jun-2023 04:11:54 UTC] PHP Notice:  Function WP_User_Query::query was called <strong>incorrectly</strong>. User queries should not be run before the <code>plugins_loaded</code> hook. Please see <a href="https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/debugging-in-wordpress/">Debugging in WordPress</a> for more information. (This message was added in version 6.1.1.) in /nas/content/live/staloysiuscstg/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5865
[20-Jun-2023 04:11:57 UTC] PHP Notice:  Function WP_User_Query::query was called <strong>incorrectly</strong>. User queries should not be run before the <code>plugins_loaded</code> hook. Please see <a href="https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/debugging-in-wordpress/">Debugging in WordPress</a> for more information. (This message was added in version 6.1.1.) in /nas/content/live/staloysiuscstg/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5865
[20-Jun-2023 04:12:00 UTC] PHP Notice:  Function WP_User_Query::query was called <strong>incorrectly</strong>. User queries should not be run before the <code>plugins_loaded</code> hook. Please see <a href="https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/debugging-in-wordpress/">Debugging in WordPress</a> for more information. (This message was added in version 6.1.1.) in /nas/content/live/staloysiuscstg/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5865
[20-Jun-2023 04:12:02 UTC] PHP Notice:  Function WP_User_Query::query was called <strong>incorrectly</strong>. User queries should not be run before the <code>plugins_loaded</code> hook. Please see <a href="https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/debugging-in-wordpress/">Debugging in WordPress</a> for more information. (This message was added in version 6.1.1.) in /nas/content/live/staloysiuscstg/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5865
[21-Jun-2023 03:13:50 UTC] PHP Notice:  Function WP_User_Query::query was called <strong>incorrectly</strong>. User queries should not be run before the <code>plugins_loaded</code> hook. Please see <a href="https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/debugging-in-wordpress/">Debugging in WordPress</a> for more information. (This message was added in version 6.1.1.) in /nas/content/live/staloysiuscstg/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5865
[21-Jun-2023 03:13:54 UTC] PHP Notice:  Function WP_User_Query::query was called <strong>incorrectly</strong>. User queries should not be run before the <code>plugins_loaded</code> hook. Please see <a href="https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/debugging-in-wordpress/">Debugging in WordPress</a> for more information. (This message was added in version 6.1.1.) in /nas/content/live/staloysiuscstg/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5865
[21-Jun-2023 03:13:56 UTC] PHP Notice:  Function WP_User_Query::query was called <strong>incorrectly</strong>. User queries should not be run before the <code>plugins_loaded</code> hook. Please see <a href="https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/debugging-in-wordpress/">Debugging in WordPress</a> for more information. (This message was added in version 6.1.1.) in /nas/content/live/staloysiuscstg/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5865
[21-Jun-2023 03:13:58 UTC] PHP Notice:  Function WP_User_Query::query was called <strong>incorrectly</strong>. User queries should not be run before the <code>plugins_loaded</code> hook. Please see <a href="https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/debugging-in-wordpress/">Debugging in WordPress</a> for more information. (This message was added in version 6.1.1.) in /nas/content/live/staloysiuscstg/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5865
[23-Jun-2023 00:30:19 UTC] PHP Notice:  Function WP_User_Query::query was called <strong>incorrectly</strong>. User queries should not be run before the <code>plugins_loaded</code> hook. Please see <a href="https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/debugging-in-wordpress/">Debugging in WordPress</a> for more information. (This message was added in version 6.1.1.) in /nas/content/live/staloysiuscstg/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5865
[23-Jun-2023 00:30:25 UTC] PHP Notice:  Function WP_User_Query::query was called <strong>incorrectly</strong>. User queries should not be run before the <code>plugins_loaded</code> hook. Please see <a href="https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/debugging-in-wordpress/">Debugging in WordPress</a> for more information. (This message was added in version 6.1.1.) in /nas/content/live/staloysiuscstg/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5865
[23-Jun-2023 00:30:27 UTC] PHP Notice:  Function WP_User_Query::query was called <strong>incorrectly</strong>. User queries should not be run before the <code>plugins_loaded</code> hook. Please see <a href="https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/debugging-in-wordpress/">Debugging in WordPress</a> for more information. (This message was added in version 6.1.1.) in /nas/content/live/staloysiuscstg/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5865
[23-Jun-2023 00:30:29 UTC] PHP Notice:  Function WP_User_Query::query was called <strong>incorrectly</strong>. User queries should not be run before the <code>plugins_loaded</code> hook. Please see <a href="https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/debugging-in-wordpress/">Debugging in WordPress</a> for more information. (This message was added in version 6.1.1.) in /nas/content/live/staloysiuscstg/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5865
[23-Jun-2023 00:32:39 UTC] PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/nas/content/live/staloysiuscstg/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates_c/CachedExtLoader.d798c88b1da2dfdd65684e016c65ef77.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /nas/content/live/staloysiuscstg/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Extension/ClassLoader.php on line 87
[23-Jun-2023 00:32:40 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Exception\IOException: Cannot rename "/nas/content/live/staloysiuscstg/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates_c/CachedCiviContainer.d798c88b1da2dfdd65684e016c65ef77.phpTnZb1v" to "/nas/content/live/staloysiuscstg/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates_c/CachedCiviContainer.d798c88b1da2dfdd65684e016c65ef77.php". in /nas/content/live/staloysiuscstg/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/symfony/filesystem/Filesystem.php:290
Stack trace:
#0 /nas/content/live/staloysiuscstg/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/symfony/filesystem/Filesystem.php(696): Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Filesystem->rename('/nas/content/li...', '/nas/content/li...', true)
#1 /nas/content/live/staloysiuscstg/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/symfony/config/ResourceCheckerConfigCache.php(124): Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Filesystem->dumpFile('/nas/content/li...', '<?php\n\nuse Symf...')
#2 /nas/content/live/staloysiuscstg/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Core/Container.php(83): Symfon in /nas/content/live/staloysiuscstg/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/symfony/filesystem/Filesystem.php on line 290
[23-Jun-2023 00:33:36 UTC] PHP Notice:  Function WP_User_Query::query was called <strong>incorrectly</strong>. User queries should not be run before the <code>plugins_loaded</code> hook. Please see <a href="https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/debugging-in-wordpress/">Debugging in WordPress</a> for more information. (This message was added in version 6.1.1.) in /nas/content/live/staloysiuscstg/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5865
[23-Jun-2023 00:33:40 UTC] PHP Notice:  Function WP_User_Query::query was called <strong>incorrectly</strong>. User queries should not be run before the <code>plugins_loaded</code> hook. Please see <a href="https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/debugging-in-wordpress/">Debugging in WordPress</a> for more information. (This message was added in version 6.1.1.) in /nas/content/live/staloysiuscstg/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5865
[23-Jun-2023 00:33:42 UTC] PHP Notice:  Function WP_User_Query::query was called <strong>incorrectly</strong>. User queries should not be run before the <code>plugins_loaded</code> hook. Please see <a href="https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/debugging-in-wordpress/">Debugging in WordPress</a> for more information. (This message was added in version 6.1.1.) in /nas/content/live/staloysiuscstg/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5865
[23-Jun-2023 00:33:45 UTC] auditor:event=upgrader_process_complete_plugin {"plugin":"akismet/akismet.php","type":"plugin","action":"update","blog_id":1,"event":"upgrader_process_complete_plugin","current_user_id":3,"remote_addr":"35.245.50.252"}
[23-Jun-2023 00:34:07 UTC] PHP Notice:  Function WP_User_Query::query was called <strong>incorrectly</strong>. User queries should not be run before the <code>plugins_loaded</code> hook. Please see <a href="https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/debugging-in-wordpress/">Debugging in WordPress</a> for more information. (This message was added in version 6.1.1.) in /nas/content/live/staloysiuscstg/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5865
[23-Jun-2023 00:34:09 UTC] PHP Notice:  Function WP_User_Query::query was called <strong>incorrectly</strong>. User queries should not be run before the <code>plugins_loaded</code> hook. Please see <a href="https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/debugging-in-wordpress/">Debugging in WordPress</a> for more information. (This message was added in version 6.1.1.) in /nas/content/live/staloysiuscstg/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5865
[23-Jun-2023 00:34:13 UTC] auditor:event=upgrader_process_complete_plugin {"plugin":"gravityforms/gravityforms.php","type":"plugin","action":"update","blog_id":1,"event":"upgrader_process_complete_plugin","current_user_id":3,"remote_addr":"35.245.50.252"}
[23-Jun-2023 00:36:21 UTC] PHP Notice:  Function WP_User_Query::query was called <strong>incorrectly</strong>. User queries should not be run before the <code>plugins_loaded</code> hook. Please see <a href="https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/debugging-in-wordpress/">Debugging in WordPress</a> for more information. (This message was added in version 6.1.1.) in /nas/content/live/staloysiuscstg/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5865
[23-Jun-2023 00:36:24 UTC] PHP Notice:  Function WP_User_Query::query was called <strong>incorrectly</strong>. User queries should not be run before the <code>plugins_loaded</code> hook. Please see <a href="https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/debugging-in-wordpress/">Debugging in WordPress</a> for more information. (This message was added in version 6.1.1.) in /nas/content/live/staloysiuscstg/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5865
[23-Jun-2023 00:36:27 UTC] PHP Notice:  Function WP_User_Query::query was called <strong>incorrectly</strong>. User queries should not be run before the <code>plugins_loaded</code> hook. Please see <a href="https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/debugging-in-wordpress/">Debugging in WordPress</a> for more information. (This message was added in version 6.1.1.) in /nas/content/live/staloysiuscstg/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5865
[23-Jun-2023 00:36:29 UTC] PHP Notice:  Function WP_User_Query::query was called <strong>incorrectly</strong>. User queries should not be run before the <code>plugins_loaded</code> hook. Please see <a href="https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/debugging-in-wordpress/">Debugging in WordPress</a> for more information. (This message was added in version 6.1.1.) in /nas/content/live/staloysiuscstg/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5865
```

Can someone please advise me what the issue may be? It's only a few times but I want to get to the bottom of it.

The site has HTTP authenticated configured to limit public access.

I've attached the system status screen within the plugin too for reference:

[image]

Comment: It would be useful if you post the error that triggered the backtrace.

Comment: Hi Christian, There is only one other log entry prior to the PHP Fatal error, which is as follows:  PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/nas/content/live/staloysiuscstg/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates_c/CachedExtLoader.d798c88b1da2dfdd65684e016c65ef77.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /nas/content/live/staloysiuscstg/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Extension/ClassLoader.php on line 87

Comment: What I meant was that you haven't posted the fatal error itself - just the backtrace.

Comment: I had to get our hosting provider to activate the debug logs. I havn't been able to replicate the error as yet, but will let you know when I do and send the debug log file here - Adam

Comment: Hi Christian, the site has emailed me an error with the CiviCRM plugin this morning: 
debug.log file as follows:
https://boylenadelaide-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/support_boylen_com_au/EcrhmgVixndFk_P5HLAvR-YBneerpMZuj8kkLsc4jgXR8w?e=D51QTU

Comment: Please edit your question to include the error rather than sticking a link to a file in a comment. It will make it much easier to help you.

Comment: Hi Kapn - done! Thank you - Adam

Comment: Hi Adam, looks like you should check that your web user has the correct permissions on your `wp-content/uploads/civicrm` folder and sub-folders.

Comment: Hi Christian, it looks like its a 775 for the permissions on that folder, I also verified uploads and wp-content have the correct permissions too. Our hosting provider has mentioned that because the site has http authentication on it (password protected) that would cause a 401 error if there is an outside source trying to ping the site. Would this be the problem? I will remove the http authentication and see if we continue to get this error - Adam

Comment: @Boylen You mentioned the permissions but not the file owner - confirm that the user that the PHP process runs as owns the `templates_c` folder and is able to traverse all parent folders to reach `templates_c`?

Comment: Hey, our hosting provider has mentioned that it should be able to traverse all parent folders to reach templates_c, the site provided another php error this morning, as mentioned above even after I have turned off the http authentication (password protection). This error occurs when were not on the site, so I cant determine whats causing it, it must be something that automatically runs from the CiviCRM plugin. Can we connect on a different forum somewhere were we can provide you the full debug log and perform troubleshooting please?

Comment: I also forgot to mention our hosting partner has applied the following web rule for requests from the user agent civicrm to not be blocked - sometimes our cloudflare proxy could block requests so we've put in the web rule as a precautionary measure. not sure it will fix the above issue though

Comment: Hi all- can I get an update on this one? Thank you.

Comment: Hi CiviCRM- I have updated the plugin to civicrm v5.63.2, Can I please get an update on this fatal error? It's still on going and occurs a few times a week without us navigating to the website.

Comment: Hi CiviCRM - I've looked at other articles and have come across this one:
https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/26424/new-install-civi-5-4-0-getting-uncaught-symfony-rename-error-and-blank-screen

Would this be a solution to my problem?